# invertibility of spherical transformation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

For the question below, would it be enough to find the points on the boundary of the sphere and just exclude those.  Would the sphere be invertible every else?

Thanks in advance.

> Near which points $(r, \phi, \theta)$ is the following spherical coordinate transformation in space invertible?
>
> $x=r\cos\phi \sin\theta$
>   $y=r\sin\phi \sin\theta$
>
> $z=r\cos\theta$

Comment: The sphere has no boundary. ..

Comment: Since no boundary exists that would probably just leave the restriction of the horizontal plane?  Since it wouldn't be one-to-one there, which would fail the condition of the inverse function theorem?  Am I on the right track, or are there other restrictions I should consider?  or should I approach the problem differently?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

John, I will quote wolfram mathworld here:

> Blockquote
>   The spherical coordinates (r,theta,phi) are related to the Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) by
>   r   =   sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)
>   (1)
>   theta   =   tan^(-1)(y/x)
>   (2)
>   phi =   cos^(-1)(z/r),
>   (3)
>   where r in [0,infty), theta in [0,2pi), and phi in [0,pi], and the inverse tangent must be suitably defined to take the correct quadrant of (x,y) into account.